# Swiper using React Native's FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to make my horizontal FlatList (with paging enabled) scroll to left or right in a way that the content is always in the center of the screen and the next and the previous content still appear.

Something like this (for the horizontal actions)[image]

But unfortunately when the flat list is scrolling, the lenght of the scroll is the same of the width of the flat list or its parent and I can't the effect I want. 
[image: print of the app]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Our company had a similar need, but none of the existing plugins completely fulfilled our use case. We ended up creating our own and open-sourcing it: [`react-native-snap-carousel`](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/).

The plugin is now built on top of `FlatList` (versions >= 3.0.0) and provides **previews** (the effect you were after), **snapping effect**, **parallax images**, **RTL support**, and more.

You can take a look at the [showcase](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel#showcase) to get a grasp of what can be achieved with it. If you decide to give it a try, do not hesitate to share your feedback with us; we're always trying to improve it.

[image: react-native-snap-carousel archriss showcase]
[image: react-native-snap-carousel archriss aix]

---

Edit : [two new layouts](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/#layouts-and-custom-interpolations) have been introduced in version `3.6.0` (one with a stack of cards effect and the other with a tinder-like effect). Enjoy!

[image: react-native-snap-carousel stack layout]
[image: react-native-snap-carousel tinder layout]

Comment: @bend I love react-native-snap-carousel and I've been using it for a while!  I'm having one issue major issue I can't solve and I'm working if you have any input!  When the screen renders that I'm using snap-carousel on, only the first card renders and the rest of the carousel doesn't.  It's really problematic for me because users don't know that there is a carousel.  Do you have any suggestions?  I can make a separate stackoverflow post if that's helpful!

Comment: @bzlight Please open an issue [here](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/issues) and make sure to follow the contributing guidelines. That's the best way to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 12):

I used react-native-snap-carousel and while the animations and customizations are quite nice, it's really hard to style because it does not behave like a normal view, and it doesn't render properly inside a ScrollView.

Instead, I reverted to a normal FlatList with some instructions from [this page](https://blog.yikkok.com/2019/03/03/how-to-create-snap-effect-on-flatlist/)

The setup:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.data}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
    horizontal={true} // row instead of column
    // Add the 4 properties below for snapping
    snapToAlignment={"start"} 
    snapToInterval={this.IMAGE_WIDTH + 10} // Adjust to your content width
    decelerationRate={"fast"}
    pagingEnabled
/>
```

Comment: Please adjust `decelerationRate="fast"` and you can remove `snapToAlignment` since it's set to `start` by default (iOS)

Answer (score 2):

You might be better served using a library for this. I've used `react-native-carousel` to good success for an identical use case. Github [here](https://github.com/nick/react-native-carousel). Your code would look something like this:

```
import Carousel from 'react-native-carousel'

getListItems() {
   return [ <View>...</View>, <View>...</View>]
}

render() {
   return (
      <Carousel>
         {this.getListItems()}
      </Carousel>
   )
}
```